# "Mean": Asking for definition and intention

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

What are German equivalents of the English `mean`, as in "What does this word mean?" or "What do you mean by that?"?

How would you translate the 2 sentences? 
"What does this word mean?" --> "Was _ dieses Wort?"
"What do you mean by that?" --> "Was _ du/Sie?"

I've heard that there are several different German words for those cases but am unsure as to what words would work.

Comment: denken. *Woran denkst du damit*, das würde ich sagen. Das ist verständlich, aber wahrscheinlich nicht korrekt.

Answer (score 3):

*What does this word mean?*

> Was **bedeutet** dieses Wort?
>
> Was **meint** dieses Wort?

The tricky difference is *bedeuten* asks for the meaning of the word as in the dictionary whereas *meinen* asks for the meaning in the current context. It's the same in the following sentence.

> Was **meinst** du damit?

*What do you mean by that?*

Again, *meinen* asks for the meaning in context.

Another matching word is *heißen*.

> Was **heißt** das?

*What does it mean?*

You are expecting a very thorough answer on this question.

Comment: ```Was heißt das?``` seems to ask "What is this called?" rather than "What is this word's definition?" or "What does that mean in this context?".

Comment: *Bedeuten* and *heißen* are pretty synonymous. The only obvious counterexamples are *Wie heißen Sie?* and *Ich heiße dich willkommen.*

Comment: @JohnZhau A better translation for "What is this called?" is "Wie nennt man das?". Maybe "Wie heißt das?", but that also feels strange. *Heißen* in this meaning can be used for names of people, not definitions of things.